# Installing QCMBundle-Override service

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm trying to install the qcm bundle https://github.com/avoo/QcmCoreBundle and I didn't understand what i have to do in this step :

Override service

```
qcm_core:
    service:
        statistics:
            class: MyBundle\Statistics\Class // For better compatibility extends the Model\QuestionnaireStatistics
            template: MyBundle\Answers\Template\Class // You need to implements the qcm TemplateInterface
```

Is this error is due to this step

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]  
  The service "qcm_core.form.type.user" has a dependency on a non-existent pa   
  rameter "qcm_core.model.user.class". Did you mean one of these: "fos_user.m   
  odel.user.class", "qcm.model.user.class", "qcm_core.template.class", "qcm_c   
  ore.controller.user.class", "qcm_core.form.type.user.class"?
```

Comment: It seems that this step isn't required, you may use this bundle without overriding default services

Comment: i had this error , i thought it's due to this step           [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]  
  The service "qcm_core.form.type.user" has a dependency on a non-existent pa   
  rameter "qcm_core.model.user.class". Did you mean one of these: "fos_user.m   
  odel.user.class", "qcm.model.user.class", "qcm_core.template.class", "qcm_c   
  ore.controller.user.class", "qcm_core.form.type.user.class"?

Comment: You should ask for this issue directly to the bundle owner on github.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the service, you are missing an indent:

```
qcm_core:
    service:
        statistics:
            class: MyBundle\Statistics\Class // For better compatibility extends the Model\QuestionnaireStatistics
            template: MyBundle\Answers\Template\Class // You need to implements the qcm TemplateInterface
```